# Word that Stands Out Clear

Tags: word, cipher

I

have a message in

a

very new

kind of question page

a

way to find it is

to look

closer at the word

that stands out clear

a

way

to learn to

remember to find help

the

reverse cipher will lead

your way on

what you want to do with a

tap in

life

fourteen

seven

five thousand eight hundred

Minor Hint:

> This puzzle was simple enough for me to make on my phone in 15 minutes. Don’t look too deeply here.

Minor Hint #2:

> Stuff was changed around O.o, in addition, there are a *lot* of red herrings in this puzzle. Only one line holds real importance to the answer, but it's mixed up.

Minor Hint #3:

> Think about why there are so many unnecessary line breaks, and also why a lot of them may only have one letter.

Comment: does the cipher tag apply?

Comment: somewhat. i'll add it

Comment: then i guess thats the only line important as you already hinted out :P

Comment: not necessarily, but maybe

Comment: I also know somehow either the number or learn/remember parts have something to do with the answer along with the cipher tag.. just dont know what!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what I did was

> Count the letters in each line (not spaces) because of the unnecessary line breaks

And ended up with

> 1 14 1 8 18 1 13 6 15 18 1 3 9 18 3 21 9 20 5 4 8 5 24

And then

> A1Z26 => ANAGRAMFORACIRCUITEDHEX, which when parsed looks like ANAGRAM FOR A CIRCUITED HEX

As brought to my attention by JGibbers, this comes to

> EXCITED RAICHU, which is OP. This does, I suppose, stand out.

Comment: rot13: n pvephvgrq urk vf na nantenz sbe rkpvgrq envpuh (gur hfre jub znqr guvf cbfg). Abg fher vs vg'f gur nafjre be n pyhr be n erq ureevat be abg. ohg vg'f cebzvfvat!

Comment: @JGibbers (rot13) lrnu gung'f vg. ntnva, jnfa'g tbvat vagb gbb znal pbzcyvpngvbaf. v'yy npprcg guvf nafjre jura vg nqqf gur fbyhgvba

Comment: Oh, good spot @JGibbers! I've edited that in. I had locked myself into looking for one word because of the Word tag.